# su -c taking arguments from command inside quote

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

**CODE**

```
repoPath=/var/www/vhosts/www
user=www-data

showCommands=1

execCmd()
{
    local cmd="$@";

    if [ -n "$showCommands" ]; then
        log "$cmd" "CMD";
    fi

    if [ ! -n "$noExecute" ]; then
        echo "$($cmd)";
    fi
}

suCmd()
{
    echo "$(execCmd su - $user -c \"$@\")";
}

log()
{
    if [ -z $2 ]; then
        level="INFO";
    else
        level=$2;
    fi

    echo -e $(date +%F\ %T) "[$level] $1";
}

main()
{
    echo "$( suCmd git -C ${repoPath} rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD )";
}

main
```

**OUTPUT**

```
su: invalid option -- 'C'
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd

2014-12-24 18:32:34 [CMD] su - www-data -c "git -C /var/www/vhosts/www rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
```

**BUILD**

Bash: 4.3.11

Ubuntu: 14.04.1

Comment: Why do you need so many `echo`? Try replacing `echo "$(command args ...)"` with just `command args ...` Each `echo` added needs you to add one more level of escaping the special characters - `"` & `\\`...

Comment: Need to return the output

Comment: `echo "$(command args ...)"` & `command args ...` will print exactly same contents on screen, given that the quoting is proper. (plus stderr handling is messed up in echo... approach at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

This line messes up things:

```
echo "$($cmd)";
```

Just replace it by that:

```
eval "$@";
```

and everything works fine.